# Did Abraham de Moivre Predict His Own Death?

Tags: mathematics, divination

According to the website I was perusing, found [here](http://factsdir.com/abraham-de-moivre-a-french-mathematician-successfully-predicted-the-date-of-his-own-death-in-1754.html), it stated that a mathematician named Abraham de Moivre, predicted the date of his own death (using some nonsensical method of when he had slept for 24 hours more than usual).

> At the last point of his life, he noted that he slept 15 minutes extra
>   every night then he calculated that he would die on the day that the
>   extra 15 minutes a night accumulated to 24 hours. That day was
>   November 27, 1754, the actual day of his death. He died in London and
>   was buried at St. Martin-in-the-Fields.

I don't believe this at all.  Is it true that he predicted his own death, or is this just a myth, invented to make maths seem more interesting to little kiddies?

Comment: Wikipedia recounts the story, and attributes it to [History of Mathematics](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=mGJRjIC9fZgC&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn%3A9780821821022&pg=PA229) which repeats the claim on p229 but doesn't provide references.

Comment: So we can assume it is a myth then?

Comment: While I am skeptical of the claim, I don't think it is entirely implausible.  The psychosomatic effect has been demonstrated to be very strong; if he believed in his own prediction strongly enough, he very well could have found a way—consciously or sub-consciously—to fulfill it.

Comment: Yes thanks Esultanik, that is possible, and a very interesting topic in its own.

Comment: I didn't intend my comment to say it was a myth - just that there was an obvious deadens that others could avoid. Given he was close to death and knew it, it could be merely a coincidence rather than a myth.

Comment: I can predict every *death* with 100% certainty; *time and place* of those deaths is harder.

Comment: this seems like an anomaly of what life insurance companies do every day, nothing actually remarkable.

Comment: This question has a very nice answer on the History of Mathematics SE: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/336

(spoiler: no)